# sql find missing associations

Tags: mysql

I have a table of `items` with a belongsTo association to a `books` table with the foreignKey `book_id`. How can I find `items` that have a `book_id` but there is no record in `books` with that ID? The reason is somehow the `books` record was deleted but the associated `items` records were not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if each book has an ID then try this

```
select * from items where book_id not in (select ID from books)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select i.* 
from items as i
left join books as b
on i.book_id = b.id 
where b.id is null
```

Comment: This may be MUCH faster depending on your DB size and configuration, so try it out.